# Solving $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sin(10x+6y)$. Why doesn't my approach work?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I do not want the solution to this question. I want to know why we cannot apply what I did.

> A curve through origin satisfies $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sin(10x+6y)$. Find it.

**My method:**

Let $10x+6y=t$

This gives $\frac{dt}{dx}-6\sin t=10$

Integrating factor is -6 and I solved it.

**Correct method:**

After assuming $t$, $\frac{dt}{6\sin t+10}=dx$ and then followed by integrating it. This proves to be very tedious with to many substitutions.

We can assume $1$ multiplied with $-6$ as $x^0$.

Comment: Your integrating factor does not work. What makes $-6$ an integrating factor?

Comment: Did you integrate with respect to $t$ or to $x$? If you integrate with respect to $x$ you should get the form given in the correct method.

Comment: Why did you use integrating factor?  this was homogeneous separable differential equations

Comment: If you want to use integration factor it is formed  $\frac{dy}{dx}+py=q$ where $p$ and $q$ is function of $x$ otherwise you can't use integration factor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dt}{dx}-6\sin t=10$$
For the integrating factor method you need to have a DE of the form:
$$y'+\alpha (x)y=\beta (x)$$
This is not the case. The DE is not linear.
$$\frac{dt}{dx}-6\sin t=10$$
The DE is separable. So method 2 is correct.